# Microsoft FileProviders Error (File does exist) [Docker]

Tags: c#, docker, file, dockerfile, filenames

I am currently trying to dockerize my project and I am getting a really strange error that I can't seem to fix. This error prevents me from using docker run and it doesn't change no matter what. I have tried to delete any and all code related to pathing for files and still nothing changes which makes no sense to me. Below are all my files and the relevant code.

**P.S** This error never popped up during runtime or during build, only after creating the first docker image and trying to run it.

**Command:**

```
C:\Users\Jonathan\Downloads\College_DB\WebAPI\WebAPI [main ↓1 +1 ~10 -0 !]> docker run -p 5000:5000 webapi
```

**Error:**

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: /app/Photos/
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in /src/Program.cs:line 30
```

**Program.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

...

// Use files (photo files)
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Photos")),
    RequestPath = "/Photos"
});
```

**ONLY other mention of pathing to /Photos: ProfessorController.cs:**

```
var physicalPath = _env.ContentRootPath + "/Photos/" + filename;

                using (var stream = new FileStream(physicalPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    postedFile.CopyTo(stream);
                }
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY WebAPI.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore "WebAPI.csproj"

COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish "WebAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /publish

FROM build AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /publish .
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebAPI.dll"]
```

**Files Imgur:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYP7A.jpg

**EDIT:** Added Dockerfile

Comment: You need to create that folder after deployment (You can create it in your docker file.) or in the code, you check if it exists if not create it. And if your aim is to store photos uploaded you may want to use a mount. This way you will lose that folder for every deployment you make.

Comment: I completely forgot to post my dockerfile, please take a look, I kind of thought the dockerfile might have been the problem but I re-did it multiple times in different ways and still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
COPY . .  => COPY . ./
WORKDIR /src => WORKDIR /app
```

**This seems to have fixed the issue for me**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).